# Can the helloworld-spring-webapp from Jersey 2.5 examples be deployed on WebSphere 7 ?

Tags: maven-2, spring-3, websphere-7, java-6, jersey-2.0

I was able to deploy it on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5 but not on 7. I understand that WebSphere 7 needs Servlet 2.5 and below. Updating POM with latest versions of Jersey & Spring with Java 6, still throws runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will not be able to deploy it on Weblogic 7.
I was trying to deploy Jersey 2.5 on Weblogic 10.3.5 but was not able to do that as Maven is downloading the dependencies of JAX-RS 2.0 which requires java 1.7 and weblogic 10.3.5 supports till java 1.6.

I tried that on WebSphere 7.0 just now but unable to deploy it.

Comment: Just Note: JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey 2.x is compiled using JDK6 so this is not a problem. There might be problems with JAX-RS 1.1 on the system class-path of an app-server (not a case of WLS 10.3.5 AFAIK) or servlet version.